# What is the meaning of 建设 here？

Tags: meaning

I have this text from my book. I thought 建设 means 'build, construct', by association maybe 'develop', but I can't figure out what it is doing in the second sentence. I put the 3 sentences for context. Any tips out there?

I don't much care for 'use for copyright building'.

尽管在网络上播放电视剧，电影的盗版现象仍然存在，但人们的版权意识已经越来越强。目前，优酷网融资的几千万美元中，超过一亿元人民币将用于版权建设。悠视网则表示正在筹备一个版权基金，基金规模达十几亿元人民币，主要用于购买影视版权。

Comment: googled ＂copyright development＂yet？

Answer (score 4):

You should really think of it like "establishing" given the context.

目前，优酷网融资的几千万美元中，超过一亿元人民币将用于版权建设 =

Currently, out of the 10s of millions of USDs that Youku has financed, over 100 million RMBs are being used to establish copyright protection [for their videos].

Comment: So, the money is not being used to pay royalties, but to 'establish legal ownership of copyright, which may then increase income from royalties'. Is that right? I thought they were somehow referring to funds set aside to pay for the use of other people's copyrighted material, be it films, MVs, whatever.

Comment: I think the next sentence makes the point that you thought of originally: "购买影视版权". That makes it clear that Youshi is buying rights to videos (presumably to play on their website).